# Can uppper_bound be expressed in terms of lower_bound

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search

For a array can i calculate the upper_bound of a number in array using its lower_bound always.

For ex we are given an array:
  `2 3 4 4 4 5 6`
 we are to find `upper_bound` of 4 which is at index 5 (2 is at 0th index). We can find it using `lower_bound(4+1)`.

Similarly I can see that almost in everycase if we want to calculate `upper_bound` of n then we can calculate it using `lower_bound(n+1)`.

Is there any case where this property doesn't hold.

Comment: Try it with something like `[1.1 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.21]`. In this particular case, you can visually inspect to see that using lower_bound with (say) 1.205 will work, but 2 clearly won't. But nearly the only way to know that is to find the upper bound, then ensure than you increment by less than the difference between the upper bound of what you want, and whatever happens to be next in the input. With integers it's easy. With floating point, not always quite so simple.

Comment: @JerryCoffin you can fix that by using `std::nextafter` instead of `+1`. But I wouldn't advise searching a container with floating point unless you really know what you're doing. Too easy to get off-by-one errors.

Comment: Yes, for integers adding 1 will give you the upper bound, except in the degenerate case of trying to simulate upper_bound on `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Or to generalize a bit more: Yes, it works--except when it doesn't work.

Comment: Try it with something like `["fifth", "fish", "fish", "fish", "fit"]`

Answer (score 0):

Of course,you can also get a correct answer by this way in some questions,but some other questions will return a wrong answer,such as this code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n=3;
    int a[10]={ -500, 2147483647, 2147483647};

    int t = upper_bound(a,a+n,2147483647)-a;
    int k = lower_bound(a,a+n,2147483647+1)-a;
    cout << "upper_bound: " << t << "  " << a[t]<<endl;
    cout << "lower_bound: " << k << "  " << a[k]<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Key=2147483647,  index1=3,  index2=0.

You can judge all the value in the array smaller than the key by the index1 equals to 3, but you can not get the right answer by the "lower_bound" way.

For 2147483647+1 = -2147483648, it's smaller than any element in an array.